# Visual Basic 2010 express won't install

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When I try to install visual basic 2010 express, it downloads it and then installs it, next to all the installs I get all green ticks, but then it says setup failure, did not attempt to install Visual basic 2010 express - ENU.

Answer (score 0):

i figured, if you install Windows install cleanup and remove all vb 2010 or vb 2008 it lets you install the program without errors.

Comment: http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/9/d/e9d80355-7ab4-45b8-80e8-983a48d5e1bd/msicuu2.exe

Comment: here is the download above --->>>